# React - How to generate dynamic form

Tags: reactjs

I have one form in which i need to add dynamic details for contacts object. I need to send data in below format to API

Payload:

```
{
  name: "The org name",
  detail: "The org detail",
  attributes: {
    address: {
      lines: [],
      city: "",
      state: "",
      country: "India",
      zip: ""
    },
    contacts: [
      {
        name: "abc",
        phone: "PH"
      },
      { 
        name: "x", 
        phone: "PH" 
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Everything is done but i don't how to set contacts form dynamically . below is my form code

```
export default class OrganizationForm extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: this.props.match.params.id ? true : false,
    organizationForm: {
      name: "",
      detail: "",
      type: "org",
      attributes: {
        contacts: [{
          name: '',
          phone: ''
        }],
        address: {
          lines: [],
          city: "",
          state: "",
          country: "",
          zip: ""
        }
      }
    },
    errors: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    if (match.params.id) {
      OrganizationService.getOrganization(match.params.id)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            this.setState({
              organizationForm: { ...response.data },
              loading: false
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // catch this error on state and show user regarding error
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
  }

  handleChange = change => {
    const newState = {
      organizationForm: {
        ...this.state.organizationForm,
        ...change
      }
    };
    this.setState(newState);
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = currentLoggedInUser().belongs.id;
    var callCategoryApi = () => {};
    const { match } = this.props;
    const data = { ...this.state.organizationForm };
    // make this contacts part of handle change and then remove it.
    data.attributes.contacts = [];
    if (!match.params.id) {
      callCategoryApi = OrganizationService.createOrganizations(data, id);
    } else {
      callCategoryApi = OrganizationService.editOrganizations(
        data,
        match.params.id
      );
    }
    callCategoryApi
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.props.history.goBack();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { organizationForm, loading } = this.state;
    const { match } = this.props;
    if (loading) {
      // replace this loading as per design
      return <h3 style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>Loading...</h3>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="welcome-wrap">
        <br />
        <h3 className="text-center">
          {match.params.id ? "Edit Organization" : "Add Organization"}
        </h3>
        <hr />
        <Col className="create-content-wrap" sm={12}>
          <form className="">
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group required row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                Name
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={organizationForm.name}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({ name: event.target.value });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group required row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                Detail
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="detail"
                componentClass="textarea"
                value={organizationForm.detail}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({ detail: event.target.value });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                Address
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="lines"
                componentClass="textarea"
                value={organizationForm.attributes.address.lines.join("\n")}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({
                    attributes: {
                      address: {
                        ...organizationForm.attributes.address,
                        lines: event.target.value.split("\n")
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                City
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="city"
                value={organizationForm.attributes.address.city}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({
                    attributes: {
                      address: {
                        ...organizationForm.attributes.address,
                        city: event.target.value
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                State
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="state"
                value={organizationForm.attributes.address.state}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({
                    attributes: {
                      address: {
                        ...organizationForm.attributes.address,
                        state: event.target.value
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                Country
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="country"
                value={organizationForm.attributes.address.country}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({
                    attributes: {
                      address: {
                        ...organizationForm.attributes.address,
                        country: event.target.value
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                Zipcode
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="number"
                name="zip"
                value={organizationForm.attributes.address.zip}
                onChange={event => {
                  this.handleChange({
                    attributes: {
                      address: {
                        ...organizationForm.attributes.address,
                        zip: event.target.value
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
              <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
                Contacts
              </ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="number"
                name="contacts"
                // value={organizationForm.attributes.contacts}
                // onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </form>
        </Col>
        <div className="">
          <Link to="/stw/setting/organization" className="btn btn-secondary">
            Cancel
          </Link>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary ml-2"
            onClick={event => this.handleSubmit(event)}
          >
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There should be one add contact and remove contact button, on click of that buttons, i should add or remove contacts from form.

How can i create dynamic array of contacts from my form ?

**Update**
The form is looking below now, when i click on add contact it should add 2 more text box of name and phone, and add contact button should come below that 2 text boxex.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store and additional option in your state named currentContact like this:

```
state= {
   currentContact: {name: '', phone: ''},
   showContactForm: false,
   organizationForm: {...}
}
```

then you can do sth like this:

```
<FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
  <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
    Contacts
  </ControlLabel>
   <button onClick={this.showContactForm}>add contact</button>
     {this.state.showContactForm && 
      <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
       <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
           name
       </ControlLabel>
     <FormControl
       className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
       type="text"
       name="name"
       onChange={this.handleNameChange}
     />
       <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
           phone
       </ControlLabel>
     <FormControl
       className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
       type="text"
       name="phone"
       onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
     />

       </FormGroup>
   }
   {this.state.organizationForm.attributes.contacts.map((contact,index)=>{
       return <div>{contact.name}<button onClick={()=>{this.removeContact(index)}}>remove</button></div>
   })}
</FormGroup>
```

the removeContact function in your component should be:

```
removeContact = (index)=>{
     const {contacts} = this.state.organizationForm.attributes;           
     contacts.splice(index,1);
     this.handleChange({attributes: {contacts});
}
```

the addContact function:

```
showContactForm = (e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     if(!this.state.showContactForm){
        this.setState({showContactForm: true});
     } else {
         this.addContact(e)
     }
}
addContact = (e)=>{
     e..preventDefault();
     const {name, phone} = this.state.currentContact;
     const {contacts} = this.state.organizationForm.attributes;          
     contacts.push(this.state.currentContact);
     this.handleChange({attributes: {...this.state.organizationForm.attributes, contacts}});
}
```

the handleNameChange and handlePhoneChange functions:

```
   handleNameChange = (e)=>{
      this.setState({currentContact: {...this.state.currentContact, name: 
      e.target.value}})
   }

   handlePhoneChange = (e)=>{
      this.setState({currentContact: {...this.state.currentContact, phone: 
      e.target.value}})
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i need contacts inside of organizationForm->attributes->contacts. can you update answer with this states ?

Comment: in the addContact and removeContact, I am updating your organizationForm->attributes->contacts as I am calling your handleChange function with the new array in attributes, so the contacts array gets updated in the attributes object

Comment: Okay. but your solution is not working. whenever i click on add contact button, the page refresh it self and nothing happening

Comment: its probably because of the behavior of the button element that whenever it gets clicked, it refreshes the page by default, I have now updated the code to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Error isn't coming , but form is looking very weird, can you please check my updated question ?

Comment: the photo that you have uploaded is corrupted, can you upload it again?

Comment: @Vishal is this scenario correct ? : when the user clicks the add contact button, you want to render two inputs that gets the name and the phone and then when the user confirms these two information, you want to add it to the contacts array?

Comment: and photo is correct. i can see it. when i click on add contact button, the remove button one new remove button added. but no change in form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179729/discussion-between-mehrnaz-sa-and-vishal).